# How to identify whether the access is read or write in Sigaction?

Tags: c

I am using **Sigaction** for signal handling, and I was trying to differentiate between Read and Write access in case of "**SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault**". Check the below code for more reference.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void handler(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* ucontext)
{
    int access_type = -1;
    ucontext_t* uc = (ucontext_t *)ucontext;
    if(uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ERR] & 0x2)
    {
        access_type = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        access_type = 4;
    }
    if(access_type == 2)
    {
        mprotect(info->si_addr, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    }
    else if(access_type == 4)
    {
        mprotect(info->si_addr, sizeof(int), PROT_READ);
    }
}

int main()
{
    void *vm_ptr;
    int PAGE_SIZE = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    int vm_size = 16 * PAGE_SIZE;
    if (posix_memalign(&vm_ptr, PAGE_SIZE, vm_size))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "posix_memalign failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (mprotect(vm_ptr, vm_size, PROT_NONE))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "mprotect failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
    
    // Accessing protected memory to generate SIGSEGV
    int *ptr = (int *)vm_ptr;
    *ptr = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing is it always populates the `access_type` variable with 4, even if the original access made is "write" access. Am I missing something here? Or is there any other way to identify write access to a memory block?

Comment: Most memory or pointer errors can't be resolved, and really shouldn't be resolved. They should be *solved* by fixing the code instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I am aware of that, and it's not like I am trying to access an invalid memory with the program. I am doing mprotect with PROT_NONE to an allocated chunk by malloc and I am just working on that.

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to ask directly about the original and underlying problem you try to solve, rather than for help to fix a solution to the (for us) unknown problem. I'm sorry but your question is an example of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay, I'll update the code then.